# not able to move to another view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to move from 1st view controller -> 2nd view controller. However, it seems nothing is happening.

It is mainly from a sign-in page, so I don't need to get back to that page once I have a successful login. I'm trying right now from a button just to check.

I have 2 classes.

1. signInPage
2. optionsScreen

I need to go from 1 > 2

---

Inside signInPage.m

```
#import "optionsScreen.h"

- (IBAction)moveToNext:(id)sender {


    optionsScreen *aSecondPageController =
    [[optionsScreen  alloc]
     initWithNibName:@"optionsScreen"
     bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:aSecondPageController animated:YES];

//    [aSecondPageController release];


}
```

---

Screenshot of story board

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1y7ao4cGAYKaU0yRlVxcVg2bzA/edit?usp=sharing

Solution:

```
- (IBAction)moveToNext:(id)sender {


    NSString * storyboardName = @"Main_iPhone";

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
    UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"optionsScreen"];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?  Are you sure your button is linked (aka is `moveToNext:` being called?

Comment: No errors, it just doesn't do anything.

Comment: Add NSLog('Called'); to that method and make sure that method is being called.

Comment: Your 1st view controller needs to be in a navigation controller.

Comment: Ahhh I should've checked the google drive image... you win @rmaddy :)

Comment: @rmaddy : what do you mean by in navigation controller? Can you please tell how can that be done.

Comment: @user3768711 Please read the [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457).

Comment: Won't using navigation view controller mean - there will be a back button on the optionsScreen page ?

Comment: @user3768711 do you want a back button or no?

Comment: Nope, no back button.

Answer (score 0):

In storyboard add navigation view controller. As root view controller - perhaps by default it is table view controller, so remove it - set up 1st view controller. Adding navigation controller you can push to navigation stack as many view controllers as you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do is present the view controller modally, not push it onto the stack (which doesn't exist). Instead you should just do this. This will not show a back button by default so you'll have to add one manually:

```
optionsScreen *aSecondPageController = [[optionsScreen alloc] initWithNibName:@"optionsScreen" bundle:nil];

[self presentViewController:aSecondPageController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

To go back, in your `optionsScreen` view controller, you'll need some sort of back button right? So you can do this in your viewDidLoad:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(backPressed:);
```

Then you'll have to create a new method called `backPressed:`

```
-(void)backPressed:(id)sender {

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

---

**Edit**: it turns out you were trying to do what I explained above. I will leave the navigation controller bit for future reference.

If you are trying to use a navigation controller to push your options, which *will* give you a back button by default, then first, in your storyboard, click your sign in view controller, then at the menu bar at the top go to `Editor > Embed In... > Navigation Controller`. Then in your view controller switch method, you can do what you were trying before

```
optionsScreen *aSecondPageController = [[optionsScreen alloc] initWithNibName:@"optionsScreen" bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:aSecondPageController animated:YES];
```